# Is there a way to drop static declaration from page method?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, static, webforms

For a site I'm developing I have two html buttons, not ASP because I do not want them to postback.  For the submit button I am calling a javascript function that implements PageMethods to call a C# method from the codebehind.  Here is the code for the buttons and the javascript.

```
<fieldset id="Fieldset">
    <button onclick="SendForm();">Send</button>             
    &nbsp;
    <button onclick="CancelForm();">Cancel</button>                  
</fieldset>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendForm() {
        var email = $get("txtEmail").value;

        PageMethods.SendForm(email, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
    }

    function OnSucceeded() {
        $get("Fieldset").innerHTML = "<p>Thank you!</p>";
    }

    function OnFailed(error) {
        alert(error.get_message());
    }
</script>
```

The codebehind method shown here:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendForm(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        throw new Exception("You must supply an email address.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (IsValidEmailAddress(email))
        {
            bool[] desc = new bool[14];
            bool[] local = new bool[14];
            bool[] other = new bool[14];

            for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++)
            {
                desc[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkDesc" + i.ToString())).Checked;
                local[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkLocal" + i.ToString())).Checked;
                other[i] = ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl("chkOther" + i.ToString())).Checked;

                /* Do stuff here */
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("You must supply a valid email address.");
        }
    }
}
```

does not work unless it is declared as static.  Declaring it as static blocks me from checking the checkboxes on the page because it generates a "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" error.   So my problem can be fixed from either of two directions.  A)  Is there a way I can have this method work without declaring it as static?  B) How do I check the checkboxes if the method is static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be static, no way around that; But you can access the Page like this

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
```

and do FindControl on this page instance.

```
desc[i] = ((CheckBox)page.FindControl("chkDesc" + i.ToString())).Checked;
```

Answer (score 2):

Page Methods are a special case of the legacy ASMX web service technology. They allow you to place the service in the codebehind class for the page, and keep you from needing a separate project for the service.

But they will never be able to access anything on the page itself. You'll have to do that from the client side, and pass the values of the check boxes to the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the checkboxes, then you need to either use an UpdatePanel to do your AJAX stuff, or return something from your page method (ideally a string) and check the checkboxes based on what's returned in javascript on client.